# You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:

Tags: android, ionic, licencias

Estoy tratando de obtener una emulación de android a través de ionic. Para ello me voy a la carpeta de mi proyecto y escribo `ionic cordova emulate android`. Me encuentro que me da un "FAILURE" y dos "BUILD FAILED".
El mensaje del FAILURE es el siguiente:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>
>   > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [Android SDK Platform 26].   Before building your
>   >     project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the
>   >     installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
>   >     Manager.   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license
>   >     agreements from one workstation to another, go to
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Busco un poco por google y enseguida llego a [una pregunta del sitio de stackoverflow en inglés con varias respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760172/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-components?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), me centro en la más votada:

> The way to accept license agreements from command line has changed.
>   You can use the SDK manager which is located at:
>
> `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin` Run the sdkmanager as follows:
>
> `./sdkmanager --licenses` And accept the licenses you did not accept yet
>   but do need.
>
> See for more details the Android Studio documentation, although the
>   current documentation is missing any description on the --licenses
>   option.

Abro el cmd de windows:
introduzco `cd C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\bin` y después escribo:    `sdkmanager --licenses` y me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo aceptar la licencia del componente "Android SDK Platform 26" ?**

Comment: un update del sdk por lo general te hace saltar los acepte licencias

Comment: generalmente cuando sale eso, es que no tienes instaladala version de android para tu repo y cordova lo intenta descargar y debes aceptar lal licencia, lo que debes hacer es (Para windows) abres el sdk manager buscas tu version le das instalar y listo problema solucionado

Comment: @aloMalbarez: Por favor, publica una respuesta para que pueda validarla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalmente corriendo el updater desde el gui o linea de comandos te muestra las licencias y da la opción de aceptarlas

```
./sdkmanager --update
```

Por cada paquete que no encuentra la licencia aceptada te muestra el texto de la licencia por pantalla, fecha de la misma y pregunta `Accept? (y/N)` al ser N la opción por default es fácil saltarse alguna con un doble enter.

Para aceptar varias licencias a la vez (linux/mac):

```
$ yes | ./sdkmanager --update
```

las licencias aceptadas se guardan en `$ANDROID_HOME/licenses` si cambia el root del sdk o no está definida la variable te muestra el error, también le podes decir al manager donde buscarlas con la opción `--sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME`.
En windows esta variable la invocas así: `%ANDROID_HOME%`.

Answer (score 0):

Otro tips ingresen al cmd como administrador, o de lo contrario aparentemente se les actualiza pero realmente no lo hace, ya q sino entras como administrador igual no manda mensaje de error.

Al aceptar los términos el descarga unos archivos de Internet, es la forma de saber si en verdad se esta actualizando...

Ruta en mi caso (Puede variar dependiendo donde este instalado tu Android):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin
```

Comandos que pueden utilizar:

```
sdkmanager --update      

sdkmanager --licenses
```

Espero ayudar un poco.

En mi caso sirvio.